# What is the equivalent of firebase realtime database push in iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I create a reference to an auto-generated child location in firebase realtime database and firestore? I am able to call `push()` in Android looking for the equivalent in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift you can use `childByAutoId()` to get the same result as `push()` in the other languages.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding item to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data), and the [usage of `childByAutoId`](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/search?q=childbyautoid) in Firebase's quickstart examples.